# Comparison of the contents of two text file in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filecompare, text-comparison

I have two text files with 2.4M. I like to compare what are the differences in these two text files. I used Kompare. It worked but it is slow for a big file size. Looks like never finish the comparison.

What could be the best software in Ubuntu or Windows to compare and visualize the contents of two text files .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try **diffuse**

```
sudo apt-get install diffuse
diffuse file1 file2
```

Or Meld Diff Viewer Here's [a link](http://ubuntuguide.net/meld-diff-viewer-compare-and-merge-filesdirectories-in-ubuntu)

Comment: I have concern about speed because of file size 2.4M. Kompare ,I used, doesn't work well for big file size. Have you tried using big file size?

Comment: You can just use the diff command and add --speed-large-files parameter to your command. `diff --speed-large-files file1 file2`

Comment: Thanks let me test

Comment: if you found an answer please let us know.

Comment: Yes Meld Diff is good. And quite fast.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use diff command to display line-by-line difference between two files.

The general syntax of diff command as follows:

diff FILE1 FILE2